# Logging __FILE__ with Flurry

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, flurry

We use the Flurry SDK to gather analytics on how our users use our app.

We've been seeing a weird error where the app complains it can't connect to server, so to help troubleshoot what was going on, I added a Flurry event with parameters so I could see when this was happening.

Two of the parameters I loge are: `__FILE__` and `_cmd`

When I look at Flurry to see which method and which file this is happening in, the value for file is very odd. Almost every single `__FILE__` value is something like:

`/Users/yevgenysimkin/foo/git/iphone/foo/Classes/foo/App/Controller/ViewController.m`

I know there's more than one user triggering this event, so why does the same user show up repeatedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__FILE__` macro is expanded at the time of compile. The user yevgenysimkin is the user of the computer that the source file was compiled on, not the user running the app.

If you are making a library and giving it to many app makers, the macro is already hardcoded into the library by yevgenysimkin -- even if someone else compiles it into the entire app.